# How to resolve nuget error SSL connection on Linux Mint 20?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget, .net-5

I am getting an error when I try to load a simple project using .NET 5.0.
Apparently, it is on the Nuget package.

All answers which I have searched not worked for me, their problems it seems because of proxy settings. Be noticed that I am not under a proxy which means I have full access to all websites including de nuget.org

I am just doing this:

`dotnet run`

and aI getting these errors:

`dotnet/sdk/5.0.101/NuGet.targets(131,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.`

`dotnet/sdk/5.0.101/NuGet.targets(131,5): error :   The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.`

`dotnet/sdk/5.0.101/NuGet.targets(131,5): error :   The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot`

I believe is something because of the TLS certificate, not sure.

Important Tips:
On .Net Core 3.1 works
I am using Linux Mint 20 (Based on Ubuntu)

**My OpenSSL config:**

`OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020`

**Here the output of my .net info**

````
 Version:   5.0.101
 Commit:    d05174dc5a

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     linuxmint
 OS Version:  20
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         linux-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.101/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.1
  Commit:  b02e13abab

.NET SDKs installed:
  2.1.811 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
  2.2.402 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
  3.1.404 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
  5.0.101 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.23 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.8 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.23 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.8 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.10 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.23 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.8 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.10 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]```
````

Answer (score 0):

As I had a similar issue with an invalid certificate chain.
More specifically in my case was:

> The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
> The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: PartialChain

I found a [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/26294) thread that discusses certificate issues on a Unix machine. Which gave me a response that provided in one of the comments a solution that resolved my issue:

```
sudo update-ca-certificates  --fresh
```

The command provided a working solution for my issue and it could be a possible solution for the mentioned problem.

The command `update-ca-certificates` updates the directory `/etc/ssl/certs` that holds the SSL certificates and generates ca-certificates.crt, a concatenated single-file list of certificates. It reads the file `/etc/ca-certificates.conf`.

Each line gives a pathname of a CA certificate under `/usr/share/ca-certificates` that should be trusted. Lines that begin with "#" are comment lines and thus ignored. Lines that begin with "!" are deselected, causing the deactivation of the CA certificate in question. Certificates must have a .crt extension in order to be included by update-ca-certificates.

Additionally `--fresh` Removes symlinks in `/etc/ssl/certs` directory.

Comment: Also, I came up with these commands which allowed me to run on Unix systems
I don't remember, but I guess I generate or update certificates like you've posted 


export SSL_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
export SSL_CERT_DIR=/dev/null